# How to control the XML generation using For XML Auto

Tags: sql-server, xml

i issued this sql

```
DECLARE @v_xml   XML
SET @v_xml =(SELECT * FROM DELETED Where ID=@PKValue 
FOR xml AUTO, root('Record'),elements XSINIL)
```

and the xml i got as follows

```
<Record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DELETED>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <SpecialistID>52</SpecialistID>
    <EntryDate>2011-02-01T00:00:00</EntryDate>
    <HoursData>32.00</HoursData>
    <Row>6</Row>
    <Col>3</Col>
    <Options>rdSalvage</Options>
    <Comments>test2</Comments>
    <UpdatedBy>Tridip</UpdatedBy>
    <ModDate>2014-03-21T19:03:22.403</ModDate>
  </DELETED>
</Record>
```

i want to remove the `Record opening & closing tag` i know how to do it

```
DECLARE @v_xml   XML
SET @v_xml =(SELECT * FROM DELETED Where ID=@PKValue 
FOR xml AUTO, elements XSINIL)
```

but i do not know how to replace the `DELETED opening & closing tag` with Log
so the new xml would look like

```
  <Log>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <SpecialistID>52</SpecialistID>
    <EntryDate>2011-02-01T00:00:00</EntryDate>
    <HoursData>32.00</HoursData>
    <Row>6</Row>
    <Col>3</Col>
    <Options>rdSalvage</Options>
    <Comments>test2</Comments>
    <UpdatedBy>Tridip</UpdatedBy>
    <ModDate>2014-03-21T19:03:22.403</ModDate>
  </Log>
```

so please guide me and where to do the change. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @v_xml   XML
SET @v_xml =(SELECT * FROM DELETED AS [Log] Where ID=@PKValue 
FOR xml AUTO, elements XSINIL)
```